# MySQL C Connector / mysql_autocommit function

Tags: mysql, c, transactions, autocommit

I'm having a little trouble with the mysql connector in C.

I'm converting some (working) node.js scripts to a standalone C application, and for one part of this I need to switch off auto-commit, make two updates to the database and commit.

However, every time I call mysql_autocommit(mysql, 0); it fails - returning non-zero. I know my connection is good, since I've just completed a query and I'm operating on the results of that query.

Interestingly the MySQL logs are empty...which isn't very helpful.

Any ideas how might find out what the problem is, or fix it? The Node.js scripts were also switching off autocommit and [apparently] work.

Thanks in advance

Comment: if it's returning non-zero/failure, then check mysql_error() for the reason why.

Comment: Yes... I'm now having trouble getting it to fail (after adding the code to the print the errno and message to the log...annoyed that I hadn't added this before).

Answer (score 0):

I use this function the following way in my C application:

```
int main( int argc, char **argv ) {
  my_bool reconnect = 1;

  ...

  dbconnect();  // my function (-> conn)

  mysql_options( conn, MYSQL_OPT_RECONNECT, &reconnect );

  ...

  exit (0);
}
```

Then this code switch out the auto-commit:

```
mysql_autocommit( conn, 0 );
```

And this switch back:

```
mysql_commit( conn );
mysql_autocommit( conn, 1 );
```

Comment: Interesting, I'd not thought about the reconnect option...which I haven't set. I wonder now if my connection had actually dropped.

Comment: Here you can read more about this: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/auto-reconnect.html